# How to use UniqueEntity constraint on an encrypted field?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-validator

I'm working a project based on Symfony 4. I'm trying to make the `@UniqueEntity` works on an `@Encrypted` field, and I can't figure out how.

- Without the `@Encrypted` annotation, the `@UniqueEntity` annotation prevents the duplication
- With the `@Encrypted` annotation, the `@UniqueEntity` annotation allows the duplication

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DemoRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *      fields={"example"},
 *      ignoreNull=true,
 * )
 *
 */
class Demo implements LoggableEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Encrypted
     */
    private $example;
```

Comment: In any case, if the field is actually encrypted, it could be much harder for Symfony to check if the aren't any other fields with the same value.

Comment: ```https://packagist.org/packages/michaeldegroot/doctrine-encrypt-bundle```

Yep, that's my  issue :)

That's the solution I found to encrypt fields in the db (like emails, etc.) I can try something else if you have any suggestion.

Comment: No idea how that package works. But it doesn't make much sense to have a unique field and encrypt it. If you want to check for the field being unique without breaking the encryption, you may want to store a hash in a different field.

Comment: Let's say I'm adding a new user. I don't want to store the user email not encrypted, and in the mean time I want to avoid email duplication. How would you do that ?

Comment: "*I don't want to store the user email not encrypted*" Do you mind providing a bit of context on your use case in which e-mail addresses are considered so sensitive that you need to encrypt them *on top* of whatever at-rest encryption your RDBMS does? I've worked in some pretty high-sensitivity environments and I haven't ever seen e-mail addresses be singled out to be encrypted at the application level before being inserted to any sort of datastore.

Comment: I'm just talking about a field that contains the email as an example. But the fields have to be encrypted. It's a strong requirement in this project.

I've done some test, including some advices from the Encrypted package devs. I haven't reached a satisfying solution yet. 

Your advice seems to be the good direction: Encrypted and UniqueEntity are incompatible. One of them needs to be handled manually. I'm  currently trying to have a better understanding of the Encrypted package, to find the cleaner way to do this. 

As soon I found solution, I will get back to you guys !  Merry Xmas !

Answer (score 0):

First, I have no clue how that `Encrypted` package works, but if the content of the fields are encrypted it could be hard or impossible for the framework to check if the new value matches the the old one.

It would depend on how the field was encrypted, and how the check is made. The `UniqueEntity` is a validation check, so it's performed before the value is saved. It should first encrypt the value, and compare against the encrypted value. The Symfony annotation does not support that workflow.

You could store a hash for the field, the set the `Unique` check on the hash, not on the field. It would add quite a bit of storage to your table, though.

A naive implementation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *      fields={"emailHash"},
 *      ignoreNull=true,
 * )
 *
 */
class Foo {

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(length="128")
  * @Encrypted
  */
  private $email;

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(length="40")
  */
  private $emailHash;

  public function getEmail(): string
  {
        return $this->email; 
  }

  public function setEmail(string $email)
  {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->emailHash = hash('sha1', $email . get_class($this));
  }
}
```

Now the check will be made against the hash, which won't be encrypted but should be relatively safe to store. Note that I'm also using the classname as a "salt", so the hash is slightly more secure.

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`repositoryMethod`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#repositorymethod) key of the annotation, and create a custom repository method that takes a raw value, encrypts it, and performs the search by the encrypted value. That would imply that you understand how to use whatever facility your encryption package is using, so you could use it in your new repository method.

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! I'm gonna play around a bit, and get back to you :)